# a,b Designation for a lead author with different co-authors in the same year

Tags: biblatex, sorting

Biblatex/biber
citation sorting: `ynt`
bibliography sorting: `nyt`

Citation1 - Appeared first in 2010
Darwin et al (2010):

Citation2 - Appeared second in 2010
Darwin et al (2010)

When cited, the first one appears as: `Darwin et al (2010b)` and the second one as `Darwin et al (2010a)`.  Is this happening because the sorting is also being done on second and third authors?  Is there any way to swap the a,b designations?

Comment: Please post a complete MWE (minimum working example) of what you're looking to achieve, including the two Darwin entries. Without this information, it's going to be nearly impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: It is possible to add `sortkey`, `sortname` and `sortitle` fields in your bib entries to manually modify the sorting order to fit your needs.

Comment: @Guide Thanks.  I added sortkey={first author name} to both bib items and that did the trick.  I still wonder how it knows which one should be a and which one b.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly to do with the title sorting (the "t" in the sorting name). I assume that the name list for both citations is the same, hence the automatic "et al" truncation after the first name. You can always, if you want, make a custom sorting specification like:

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{ynct}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}
```

Here I've just modified the defauly ynt scheme to add a sort on citation order before title - perhaps that's what you would like? You can find all of the default sorting schemes for cut and paste into your document in the `biblatex.def` file that comes with biblatex.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Note however that co-author names are different between the two references (see the title), which is why the problem existed in the first place.

Comment: Ah, yes. In that case, you could adjust maxnames/minnames which also impacts how many names the sorting algorithm sees.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the very same issue by automatically filling the "sortname" field (originally from biblatex documentation):

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
\maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite=false]{
        \step[fieldsource=author]
        \step[fieldset=sortname, origfieldval, final]
        \step[fieldsource=sortname, match=\regexp{\A(.+?)\s+and.*}, replace={$1}]
    }
}
}
```

Citations should be sorted first by year and month, then by authors, so that `extrayear` indicators (a,b,...) get assigned in the right way. This sorting scheme can be globally set with the package option `sorting=ymnt`

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{ymnt}{
\sort{
    \field{presort}
}
\sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
}
\sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
}
\sort{
    \field{month}
}
\sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
}
}
```

In bibliographies I wanted to get the entries sorted by first author, then year and month, finally by all authors and title instead of the "normal" `nyt` style of author sorting which would then lead to shuffling the `extrayear` indicators. So I'm overwriting the global sort setting with `sorting=symnt` and use the following sorting scheme which splits sortname apart from the remaining author block:

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{symnt}{
\sort{
    \field{presort}
}
\sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
}
\sort{
    \field{sortname}
}
\sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
    \literal{9999}
}
\sort{
    \field{month}
}
\sort{
    \field{author}
    \field{extrayear}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
}
\sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
}
}
```